# Using framebuffer for gaussian blur 2 pass

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, blur, framebuffer

I want to apply gaussian blur in a 256x256 texture but Im having problems passing the first pass to a framebuffer and reusing it actualy result in part of image, that appear to be the texture transformed.

**Tanks the attention**

**vertex shader:**

```
void main()
{
   gl_Position = ftransform();
   gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
}
```

**fragment shader:**
I removed all the part of blurring only to tests.

```
uniform sampler2D texture_0; 
uniform float switcher;
vec4 cor;

void main()
{
   cor = vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
   vec2 position = gl_TexCoord[0].xy;

   cor = texture2D(texture_0,position);

   gl_FragColor = cor;
}
```

**initializations:**

```
glGenTextures( 1, &tex1 );
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex1 );
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, img1->getWidth(),img1->getHeight(), 0,GL_RGB,     GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);


glGenTextures( 1, &tex2 );
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex2 );
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, img1->getWidth(),img1->getHeight(), 0,GL_RGB,  GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex1 );
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex2 );

glGenFramebuffers(1,&framebuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,framebuffer);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex2,0);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

**render:**

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glLoadIdentity();

glUniform1i(loc_u_texture_0, 0);
glUniform1f(loc_switcher_1, 0);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);

glNormal3f(0, 1, 0);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
  glVertex3f(-2, -2,  -10);
  glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
  glVertex3f(2, -2,   -10);
  glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
  glVertex3f(2, 2,  -10);
  glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
  glVertex3f(-2, 2, -10);
glEnd();

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
usleep(50);

glUniform1i(loc_u_texture_0, 1);
glUniform1f(loc_switcher_1, 1);

glNormal3f(0, 1, 0);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);

  glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
  glVertex3f(-2, -2,  -10);
  glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
  glVertex3f(2, -2,   -10);
  glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
  glVertex3f(2, 2,  -10);
  glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
  glVertex3f(-2, 2, -10);
glEnd();

glutSwapBuffers();
```

Comment: Where are your `#version` directives?

Comment: Damn, deprecated code everywhere.

Comment: @genpfault I wasn't sure I needed to use it but by what I noticed its 1.1 te default, I believe.

Comment: @Vallentin I really sorry, Im very new to OpenGL and glsl, in fact is my first code without fixed pipeline, I'm trying to familiarize with it and so on I'm only trying to obtain some results to slowly understand how it work.

Comment: I understand, though I mentioned it, because I didn't know if you where aware of it.

Comment: @user2884025: you never seem to set the `glDrawBuffer` to `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0` which is required for the FBO case.

Comment: @derhass But by what I know glDrawBuffer is used to specify the color buffer used, if its front, back and so on, not to FBO color attachment points. I understanded it as a good approach to read and write at same time with double-buffering.

Comment: @user2884025: the color buffers are always part of the framebuffer. And you always have to select the color buffer(s) to draw to. As FBOs don't have front and back buffers, you should specify something which actually is defined for them.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following lines to draw a quad:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
glEnd();
```

When you reset both the projection and the modelview matrices, your primitives are not transformed and you can directly draw objects in clipping space (which is a cube with corners (-1,-1,-1) and (1,1,1)).

Also, don't use the following:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex2 );
```

if you are not going to use more than one input sampler per shader at the same time, you need only the first texture channel GL_TEXTURE0, which is set by default.

Comment: Tanks the help, it isn't translated anymore but it's still suffering some kind of scale, its showing something like 1/9 of the texture, a 256x256 image, that cover all primitive.

Comment: It display practically the desired image if the tex2 size is defined as 2.35 times the original texture size, but even obtaining the desired result I still did not understand why the use of two texture is produce this kind of transformation.